# Writing same package to different log files in different applications

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am exploring options with log4j to write messages with the same package to different log files depending on the application.  Both applications are WARs deployed to a web server.  They both use some shared packages, say com.ps.foo.  My use case is that I would like com.ps.foo messages to write to service.log when its executed withing the service WAR, and web.log when it executed within the web WAR.

We need the log4j configuration to be external to the WAR (in our local filesystem) so we can change logger properties without a redploy/restart of the web server, or else I would simply keep each log4j configuration packaged in each WAR.

I can specify the log4j configuration file as a -D option on the JVM, but then I am relegated to using the same log4j configuration.  I cannot use the same log4j configuration file as I would not be able to qualify com.ps.foo with the application, my understanding is that log4j only cares about classes.

My current design is to add a listener to each application that initializes log4j with its own unique log4j configuration when the servlet context initializes.  I would then have an application specific log4j configuration and specify com.ps.foo in each.

Any nudge in the right direction would be great.

Comment: All I can think implementing CustomFileAppender for both war file then accessing deployment details (via some global variable or descriptor?) from this appender then pick the right file to write